# Wordpress issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

> my site is www.sinteag.com,i have tried with making changes in siteurl
>   and home url in database but not able to solve it.Site is generating
>   its own url on every anchor...like if you visit the site and click on
>   read more buttons or social icons in the footer it will show the own
>   site url first then the designated url, i am stuck due to this issue.

this text is just for metting requirments
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your base `url` prefix with `http://` in http://www.sinteag.com/wp-admin/options-general.php this looks like a configuration issue, not a coding issue.

Comment: If you aren't meeting the word minimum, you aren't explaining well enough. We need a detailed description of your problem, including sample code and expected/actual behaviors.

Comment: Also, your href leads to Sinteag.com in the code, it seems. All absolute links to your own or other websites must have http:// before the URL. Otherwise, HTML thinks it's a file on your website.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 you can visit the site i have explained what the issue is and its simple not the complex...<a href="www.abc.com">testing</a>..if i write this it will generate www.sinteag.com/www.abc.com instead of www.abc.com...

Comment: Then write <a href="http:/ /www.abc.com/">testing</a> instead. (Space between the slashes so Markdown doesn't format it as a link.)

Comment: @MathSquared11235 thanks alot for your help its solved , i have wasted more than 1 hours on this stupid mistake...thanks alot...:)

Comment: @Scuzzy thanks alot to you too... :)

Comment: No problem. Do you mind accepting my answer so other people will know that the problem has been resolved? Just click the green checkmark further down where my answer is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have absolute links (which include the site domain) without `http://`.

HTML requires that you prefix all website names that explicitly state the domain with `http://` or whatever applies to the site.

So `<a href="http://sinteag.com">Lorem ipsum</a>` and similar.